# prepopulating checkboxlist in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, checkboxlist

I am trying to create a jsp[populate.jsp] page, which, when I hit should call Action and fetch data from database and then populate that into same JSP page with checkboxlists. I tried to search a lot and I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/) tutorial also:

that was helpful but in this tutorial they are first calling url `localhost:8080/checkBoxListAction`. However, I want my JSP to populate `checkboxlist` when I hit `localhost:8080/populate.jsp`.

I hope you understand my question. Please comment if you have any doubt.

Comment: "it did not help me" is very vague. can you post a more concrete question, preferably some code?

Comment: have you tried using a javascript function "onLoad" like onLoad=pupulateCheckboxes() and then in the js function invoke the servlet to execute the action?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that ? First you call Actions, then you render JSPs...

Comment: Don't understand your question, please clarify.

Comment: @AndreaLigios suppose my welcome file in web.xml is populate.jsp. So when I hit localhost:8080/ on my browser, then it should render populate.jsp with some data from database.I hope you get my point.

Comment: You are using an `MVC Framework`, but trying to bypass the `M`(odel) and `C`(ontroller) parts, to go straight to the `V`(iew)... the welcome `JSP` should be static, with a menu pointing to `Action`s... or you can use `AJAX` loading, or `redirect`, or `rewrite rules` to make the `localhost:8080/` url hitting an `Action` instead of an `JSP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I found the solution by myself. I made use of s:action tag, which you can declare in jsp and will directly call Action which you specify in action's name attribute(s:action name="SomeAction") and then you can render the result of this action into same jsp.